# Java Matcher.find() works, sometimes, but only after lunch on Tuesdays

Tags: java, android, regex

So I am creating a autocomplete/spelling checker class for a custom Android IME.  This is working pretty great, I am using Matcher.find() to search through the "dictionary" object.  I am currently using a word list of 15k words from Google.

I took this txt file and split it into sections (A-Z) to speed up the searching process by using the first letter of the string that is being checked.  The txt files are loaded from assets into a hashmap, all of this is working great.

I then use the regex expression:

```
String patternString = "\\b(" + word + ")";
```

The whole function looking like this:

```
private void findAutoCompletes(String word) {
    setAlphaDictionary(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)));
    ArrayList<String> autoCompleteList = new ArrayList<>();

    String patternString = "\\b(" + word + ")";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(alphaDictionary);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String autoCompleteWord = pullStringFromDictionary(matcher.start());

        //if currentlyCheckAgainstList does not contain the word, add it to the autoCompleteList
        if (!autoCompleteWord.isEmpty()) {
            if (!currentlyCheckingAgainstList.contains(autoCompleteWord)) {
                currentlyCheckingAgainstList.add(autoCompleteWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't always return what it should, using this tool: [RegexPlant](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) I ran some tests.  Using \b(we) as the regex expression, and [were, where, website, webcast, wendy] as strings to test against.  These words were taken from my dictionary text files.  Am I missing something?  I am still kinda new to Android development and I haven't used Java in years(3~4), I have been working in web development and iOS development until this project.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful.

Edit:  I wanted to add that is isn't always the case.  It seems to be "spotty". Most of the time I get the results I expect like typing "ill" returns [illegal, illness, illnois].

Comment: In your example, do you want those four words (`were, website, webcast, wendy`) to be returned or not? (`where` should not be returned in any case)

Comment: You haven't explained the problem very well. What unexpected results are you getting? Under what circumstances? What were the expected results? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear.  I didn't want where to be returned.  I used it in the test to make sure that it would return false for the expression, if that makes sense.  Like a control group I guess xD

Comment: Two things; First, LMFAO at the question title, I've been there, I know the feeling well. Second, have you tried `String patternString = "\\b(" + word + ")\\b";`?

Comment: I do have a function that uses "\\b(" + word +")\\b" and it works fine.  In this instance I wanted to match words in the dictionary files that match from the beginning, but not an exact match, leaving the ending open ended, if that makes sense.

Comment: *From the beginning* is the key here. Why not use `String patternString = "^(" + word + ")";`? Or to match a whole word - `String patternString = "^(" + word + ")\\b";`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew was just about to say that exact same thing lol

Comment: wait... open ended... try `String patternString = "^(" + word + ")[a-zA-Z]*";`. This basically will match any word that starts with `word` and is followed by zero or more letters (assuming that the words are separated by a non-letter character, like a whitespace, or `\s` in regex).

Comment: ... or just `\\w*` instead of `[a-zA-Z]*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I forgot about `\w`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `String patternString = "\\b(" + word + "\\w*)";`. Should work. Just tested at regex101.com. The `\w*` inside the parenthesis will ensure that the entire word is matched, not just the search term. It will match words that begin with `word` and are followed by zero or more alphabetic characters.

Comment: This was my thought, too.  And if this works, the entire word will be contained in `matcher.group()`--no need for a special method to retrieve it.  (FYI, you need two backslashes in the string literal: `"\\w*)"`).

Comment: @AlanMoore you're right, I forgot to escape the backslash in `"\w*)"`. Fixed.